# OAuth2 Authentication for internal application

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth

Do I need to have a public IP address and public DNS resolution for my application to use OAuth2?
I want to configure a login with google to an internal web application on my VPC. the application server is accessible only via VPN and it has a private IP address and uses an internal DNS record that not exposed to the internet.
the application can connect to the internet.

The application OAuth configuration require `callback_url`, is the callback URL needs to be accessible from the authorization server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback URL only needs to be contactable from the app - which most commonly is the user's browser. So private URLs are fine.

It is common for developers to use a callback URL such as http://localhost:3000/myapp/callback, and these work fine with OAuth. The Authorization Server does not itself try to make HTTP calls to the callback URL.